# linux - df command says disk 100% used, but it actually it's not

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running jenkins service and almost everyday it stops working saying the disk is full.

So I enter the instance to check and it really says `100% used`

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        987M   60K  987M   1% /dev
tmpfs           997M     0  997M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1       32G   32G     0 100% /
```

So I use NCDU to check what is occuping the space and it says `only 8gb` is used.

```
ncdu 1.10 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help
--- / -------------------------------------------------------
    3.7GiB [##########] /var
    1.7GiB [####      ] /home
    1.6GiB [####      ] /usr
    1.0GiB [##        ]  swapfile
  323.6MiB [          ] /opt
  133.8MiB [          ] /lib
   47.3MiB [          ] /boot
   43.8MiB [          ] /root
   23.1MiB [          ] /public
   19.8MiB [          ] /lib64
   12.3MiB [          ] /sbin
   10.7MiB [          ] /etc
    7.0MiB [          ] /bin
    3.7MiB [          ] /tmp
   60.0KiB [          ] /dev
e  16.0KiB [          ] /lost+found
   16.0KiB [          ] /.gnupg
   12.0KiB [          ] /run
e   4.0KiB [          ] /srv
e   4.0KiB [          ] /selinux
e   4.0KiB [          ] /mnt
e   4.0KiB [          ] /media
e   4.0KiB [          ] /local
e   4.0KiB [          ] /cgroup
.   0.0  B [          ] /proc
    0.0  B [          ] /sys
    0.0  B [          ]  .autorelabel
    0.0  B [          ]  .autofsck

Total disk usage:   8.6GiB  Apparent size:   8.6GiB  Items: 379695
```

Then I reboot the instance and the free space comes back to `only 28% used`

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        987M   60K  987M   1% /dev
tmpfs           997M     0  997M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1       32G  8.7G   23G  28% /
```

What can be causing this problem?

Additional data:

PSTREE

```
init─┬─acpid
     ├─agetty
     ├─amazon-ssm-agen───6*[{amazon-ssm-agen}]
     ├─atd
     ├─auditd───{auditd}
     ├─crond
     ├─dbus-daemon
     ├─2*[dhclient]
     ├─java─┬─sh───sudo───gulp --prod───9*[{gulp --prod}]
     │      └─67*[{java}]
     ├─lvmetad
     ├─lvmpolld
     ├─6*[mingetty]
     ├─rngd
     ├─rpc.statd
     ├─rpcbind
     ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
     ├─2*[sendmail]
     ├─sshd───sshd───sshd───bash───pstree
     ├─supervisord───2*[php]
     └─udevd───2*[udevd]
```

CRONTAB

```
* * * * * cd /home/ec2-user/laravel-prod  && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
0 1 * * * rm /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log
```

Comment: Hard to know without more data, but one possible cause is that a very large file had been deleted, but was still kept open by some process.  In such a case it will continue to take up space on disk, but will not appear in `du` listings (since it is not anywhere in the file hierarchy).  The space gets freed when the process exits, and rebooting in particular will accomplish that.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68523/find-and-remove-large-files-that-are-open-but-have-been-deleted

Comment: @NateEldredge thans for the comment. I've added additional data with pstree and crontab information.

Comment: Okay, so the info in that link will help you diagnose the problem if it happens again.  In particular `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` is a likely suspect.  You might want to have your cron job truncate the file, or restart the process that was writing to it, or better yet adopt a proper log rotation scheme.